# WebGL Rendering With Camera

Tags: angularjs, webgl

I'm just getting started with WebGL and I ran into a problem as soon as I started to incorpate a Camera object into the picture.

I have a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amctammany/qSLqY/) of my basic example in which I have a cube centered at (0, 0, 0) with the left, right, and rear walls drawn.  (I've used Angular to help reduce the amount of code I had to rewrite to the fiddle.)  I have my Matrix, Vector, Camera, and Quaternion code included.) There are controls which move the camera, and those which shift the camera angle.  My problem is that from the default position (0, 0, 0), when I move the camera left or right 1 unit (+- 1.0, 0, 0), it stops rendering that left or right wall completely, respectively.

The code to setup the WebGL buffers is as follows:

```
function setupBuffer () {
    var roomVerticeColors = [
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,

        1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0
    ];



    roomColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, roomColorBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(roomVerticeColors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var roomVertices = [
        // Left Wall
        -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,

        // Right Wall
        1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, -1.0

    ];

    roomVerticeBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, roomVerticeBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(roomVertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var roomVertexIndices = [
        // Left
        0, 1, 2,
        1, 2, 3,

        // Right
        4, 5, 6,
        5, 6, 7,
        // Back
        2, 3, 6,
        6, 7, 3,


    ];
    roomVerticesIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    roomVerticesIndexBuffer.numberVertexPoints = roomVertexIndices.length;
    console.log(roomVerticesIndexBuffer.numberVertexPoints);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, roomVerticesIndexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(roomVertexIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);


}
function getMatrixUniforms () {
    glProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(glProgram, 'uPMatrix');
    glProgram.vMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(glProgram, 'uVMatrix');
    glProgram.mMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(glProgram, 'uMMatrix');
}
function setMatrixUniforms () {
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(glProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix.elements);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(glProgram.vMatrixUniform, false, vMatrix.elements);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(glProgram.mMatrixUniform, false, mMatrix.elements);
}

function setupWebGL () {
    gl.clearColor(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, $scope.canvas.width, $scope.canvas.height);


    $scope.camera.updateMatrixWorld(true);
    $scope.camera.matrixWorldInverse.getInverse($scope.camera.matrixWorld);
    pMatrix = $scope.camera.projectionMatrix;
    vMatrix = $scope.camera.matrixWorldInverse;
    mMatrix = $scope.world.matrixWorld;

}
```

I've hard coded the cube's vertices into the controller, and then left it up to WebGL to transform them into their proper positions.  I suspect that this is the error, but I would hope that there is a way to properly calculate their positions via WebGL and render the remainder of the shape.

Any help is much appreciated,

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 1):

WebGL does not provide projecting 3D. You have to provide that by supplying shaders (small programs) with the math you want it to use to do the projection.

It's a big topic. Check out http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-3d-perspective/ or http://learningwebgl.com